# URL List generator

Tags: python, performance, beautifulsoup, lxml

The below code will read a downloaded HTML file. Uses `BeautifulSoup` and `lxml` to parse the document and extract all the URLs present in the document.

The function should return full URL, present with the domain, and no duplicates (even links with # are split and only the first part is taken). I may want to run this script 1000 times a day, efficiency is also important.

```
class Generate(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.BASE_DIR = '{}/{}'.format(
        os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir)), dirname)

    def download(self, urlx, filename):
        filepath = '{}/{}.html'.format(self.BASE_DIR, filename)
        if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
            data = subprocess.call(
                ['wget', urlx, '-O', '{}'.format(filepath)],
                stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
        return filepath

    def url_formatter(self, url, starturl):
        if starturl.endswith('/'):
            starturl = starturl[:-1]
        if '#' in url:
            url = url.split('#')[0]
        if url.startswith('/'):
            url = '{}{}'.format(starturl, url)
        if url.endswith('/'):
            url = url[:-1]
        if url.startswith('http'):
            return url
        else:
            return None

    def url_lister(self, main_url, filename, starturl, domain=False):
        startx = time.time()
        filepath = self.download(main_url, filename)
        data = open(filepath, 'rt').read()
        soup = BS(data, 'lxml')
        href_links = []
        for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            url = self.url_formatter(link['href'], starturl)
            if url is not None:
                if domain is not False and domain in url:
                    href_links.append(url)
                elif domain is False:
                    href_links.append(url)
        print(time.time() - startx)
        return sorted(list(set(href_links)))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am not sure about the `wget` via `subprocess` part - it feels quite an expensive thing to do, especially considering that you are also saving to and reading from disk for every single URL. Why don't download the pages via Python directly - e.g. with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) using a [single session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to re-use the underlying TCP connection.

Or, if efficiency is critical, consider using [`Scrapy` web-scraping framework](https://scrapy.org/) which works in a *non-blocking mode* and hence is extremely efficient for this sort of problems.

As far as HTML parsing part an `BeautifulSoup`, there is a way to speed it up as well - let `BeautifulSoup` parse links only with [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

parse_links_only = SoupStrainer('a', href=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, parse_only=parse_links_only)
```